# Django Rest Framework: how to user foreign key of related model only with POST?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two models:

```
class Album(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Track(models.Model):
   album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
   name = models.CharField()
```

I can't understand how to create a Track instance, with a POST endpoint /tracks, passing album id instead of album object, but keeping album object with GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Serializer for your class and do this:

```
 def post(self, request, albumId, format=None):
        try:
            album = Album.objects.get(pk=albumId)
        except Sensor.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        serializer = TrackSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.validated_data["album_id"] = album.id


            measurement = serializer.save()
```

Serializer that allows Track.album to be null:

```
class TrackSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    album= PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Album.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ('id', 'name;)
```

And url:

```
url(r'^albums/(?P<albumId>[0-9]+)/$', views.AlbumView.as_view(), name='albums'),
```

You post a Track object to yourURL/{albumId} to add it to album with id = albumId

Comment: post() method with arguments? Uhm... I have never seen arguments in post method; instead I always seen using request.data

Comment: albumId is argument which value is taken from url, so you POST Track object to yourulr/albums/1/(you can add tracks here for calrity)